# How to get users by name using QuickBlox SDK iOS

Tags: ios, search, quickblox

i am integrating QuickBlox SDK in iOS App.i wanted to fetch all the users with the username.how to get this done with Quickblox.what search query is to be made.Please suggest me any ideas on this.

Use Case: whenever user enters some characters in the SearchBar then i have to fetch all my QuickBlox users with that name.

Comment: check this link http://quickblox.com/developers/Users#Retrieve_API_User_by_full_name

Answer (score 1):

You should use method:

```
+ (QB_NONNULL QBRequest *)usersWithFullName:(QB_NONNULL NSString *)userFullName
                                   page:(QB_NULLABLE QBGeneralResponsePage *)page
                           successBlock:(QB_NULLABLE void (^)(QBResponse * QB_NONNULL_S response, QBGeneralResponsePage * QB_NULLABLE_S page, NSArray QB_GENERIC(QBUUser *) * QB_NULLABLE_S users))successBlock
                             errorBlock:(QB_NULLABLE void (^)(QBResponse * QB_NONNULL_S response))errorBlock;
```

where `userFullName` will be your string from the search bar

Pagination parameter (for example):

```
 QBGeneralResponsePage * page = [QBGeneralResponsePage responsePageWithCurrentPage:1 perPage:100]
```

Comment: Thank you very much.i will try and it will work it seems.

Comment: Hi, i tried the above , but i am getting status code 403 , which is Forbidden.its my urs: URL: https://api.quickblox.com/users/by_full_name.json?full_name=Jesu&page=1&per_page=100 under the hood of Alamofire API.

Comment: @ajaybabusingineedi [try this,](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/issues/382)  looks like you have a similar error

Comment: its glad to know this.i made it.Thanks for your timely sharing & help.

Comment: its working.But a small problem, in search i am getting logged in user also.but it should be excluded in the list.is that possible? how to make current user excluded in the search list.

Comment: @ajaybabusingineedi , our API returns all users including current. You should handle this situation for example by checking users' ID from response with currentUserID and not showing this user.